# How to compare one row of data to every row of data from another table in google sheet?

Tags: function, if-statement, google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

[image]
Hi everyone,

I need some helps on this task.
My goal is to determine whether the `Status` in `Column I` is accepted or not. If it is accepted, then print `Accept` in `Column I` and print the `Actual Time Accept` in `Column J` based on `Actual Time` in `Column C` , otherwise just leave it blank.

**Rules to determine the `Status`(Accept):**

- `Forecast Time` in `Input` greater than `Time` in `Output`
- The `Price` in `Column G` is greater than the `Actual Price` in `Column D`.

Once these 2 rules are fulfilled, then print `Accept` in `Column I` and print the `Actual Time Accept` in `Column J` based on `Actual Time` in `Column C` , otherwise just leave it blank.

As you can see from my formula in cell `I3`, it only compare row by row (one row in `Output` compare to one row in `input`).
What I want is comparing one row of data in `Output` to all the rows in `Input` to determine whether the `Status` is accepted or not.

### Example

For example, the 1st row in `Output`, the `Time` is `16:16:41`. We compare this `Time` with the `Forecast Time` in `Input`. The formula start to compare from the row with `Forecast Time` `16:17:43` since the `Forecast Time` in previous rows are all smaller than `16:16:41`. Since `16:17:43` greater than `16:16:41`, it fulfilled the first rules. However, the `Price` in `Output`, 216.5  is smaller than the `Actual Price` in `Input`, 216.56, so the `Status` will still be blank. The formula will move on to the next row and check the rules again.
Since the next `Forecast Time`, `16:18:02` is greater than `16:16:41` and the `Price` in `Output` is 216.5 greater than 216.48, all the rules fulfilled, so the `Status` will be `Accept` and the `Actual Time Accept` will be `21:34:00`

The link for google sheet is here in case is needed:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17coke3-oyDRLHgz79PDl3KX68kFOEte-aynVe-xEITU/edit?usp=sharing

Please give me some advice on this problem, I'm not sure this can be done without using Google Apps Script. Please let me know if you are not clear on what I'm asking about, any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: pls provide example of desired result in your sheet

Comment: Hi player, I have edited my googlesheet and questions (found some error), I hope it is clear enough. Sorry for making extra confusion

Comment: Sorry for keep editing the question because it is really complicated for me, I added in the explanation of example, hope it is cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I3 & drag down:

```
=IF(J3="",,"Accept")
```

J3 & drag down:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(FILTER(C$3:C, D$3:D<G3, B$3:B>H3), 1))
```

[image]